# Establishing a bijection between binary vectors and threshold graphs.

Tags: graph-theory

So this is a theorem in my notes...

*A graph is threshold if and only if it can be created by means of two operations - starting with a single vertex*

*1) Add a dominating vertex (adjacent to all vertices currently in the construction)*

*2) Add an isolated vertex (isolated from all vertices currently in the construction)*

So, if I associate operation 1 with a 1, and operation 2 with a 0, I should be able to describe a threshold graph with a binary vector of length $(n-1)$ and thus prove that there are $2^{n-1}$ threshold graphs on $n$ vertices.

My question is - how do I get started with proving the theorem?

The definition I have for threshold graph in my notes is as follows...
*A graph G with $n$ vertices $\{1,...,n\}$ is a THRESHOLD GRAPH if there are real numbers $a_1, ..., a_n, b$ such that the $0-1$ solutions of $\sum_i a_ix_i \leq b$ are precisely the characteristic vectors of the independent sets of G.*

this seems a little cumbersome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This point comes up in section 2 of the the following paper: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2930250/.  Diaconis doesn't prove that there are $2^{n-1}$ unlabeled threshold graphs on $n$ vertices, but one reason for that may be that he's Diaconis and is above such things.  If you can show that two graphs are equivalent iff their threshold sequences are equal, then your point is proven.  Diaconis gives two simple algorithms for moving between threshold graphs and threshold sequences in the paper.  Using these algorithms, the 'if' part is straightforward using induction and the 'only-if' part is also straightforward if you approach by contradiction.